# Logic inside of EJS filtering

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am trying to do some simple filtering using EJS (in my index.ejs file).

1. If object is NULL, do not show in HTML
2. If object field "level" contains value "1" but NOT value "2", show in HTML

`<% for(var i=0; i<mydb.length; i++) {%>
            <li><%= mydb[i].menuitem %></li>
            <% } %>`

I'm using express, so if useful this is my server.js

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  db.collection('mydb').find().toArray((err, result) => {
    if (err) return console.log(err)
    // renders index.ejs
    res.render('index.ejs', {mydb: result})
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter your data Before your data goes into the template.

// server.js

```
result = result.fillter (function(data){
  return data !== null ;
})
res.render('index.ejs', {db_areas: result})
```

// index.ejs

```
<% mydb.forEach(function(data){ %>
<%   if ( level.includes("1") && !level.includes("2") ) { %>

       <html></html>

<%   } %>
<% }) %>
```

## 8/12 eddited :

> Filter your data Before your data goes into the template.

your should put your `res.render('index.ejs', {db_areas: result})` after data is filtered. So your expression order should look like this :

// server.js

```
result = result.fillter (function(data){
  return data !== null ;
})
res.render('index.ejs', {db_areas: result})
```

Comment: Where in my node.js (I have called it server.js) does it go? I tried with no success. I've pasted my code here (http://dpaste.com/0X9SEW0) at line 45

Comment: Filter your data Before your data goes into the template.
I edited my answer, take a look. Rearrange your code, and it should work.